# Completeness axiom and least upper bound property

Tags: real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I have a doubt. In analysis we use extensively the fact the every bounded set has an infimum and a supremum.

Can we prove this?

Because for instance, when we define the Riemann Integral, we define this two objects 
$
I^+ = inf_\sigma  S(f,\sigma)
$
e 
$
I^- = sup\sigma  S(f,\sigma)
$
. Then, we say that the sets below are bounded and this imply that those quantities are well defined.

My question is: is an axiom or we can prove it?

Comment: You prove that there is an extension of the rational field that maintains order that has the least upper bound property.  You define that to be the reals.

Comment: So it's basically the definition of the reals.  The reals are the minimal ordered field containing the rationals that has the least upper bound property.  It must be proved there *is* such a field, but once that is proven, that ***IS*** the definition of the real numbers.

Comment: To prove it, you need some property which you know that the real numbers have and the rational numbers do not. Typically it is this property